# node.js - am I hammering my database?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to node and have written a program that works in development but I'm concerned about it's production performance.

In the code below, I am using my own mysqlAsync.queryEach method (let me know if you want me to share). It uses generic-pool, mysql and the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) libraries.

I have used generic-pool to share up to 10 mysql connections.

The mysqlAsync.queryEach method uses the async.forEach method which from the docs does the following.

> Applies an iterator function to each item in an array, in parallel.

```
function doSomethingWithExercises(callback) {

    mysqlAsync.queryEach("SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY id", function(subject, done) {

             mysqlAsync.queryEach("SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE id = ? ORDER BY id",[subject.id] function(exercise, done) {

                  //do something with the exercises
             },

             //then...
             function() {

                 done()

             });        

    },

    //then...
    function() {
        //done
        callback()

    });
}
```

So the first call to queryEach issues another x amount of calls to another queryEach. It could issue 1000's of simultaneous queries all at once.

In my specific use case, this process is used to build a redis cache which happens infrequently and not on every connection.

I am wondering if I should rather process queries synchronously on node?

Should I throttle my queries?

How many simultaneous queries can mysql handle?

Do people normally do everything async to get the best out of node or do you need to throttle certain resources?

Sorry if this question is to broad, I'm just trying to get my head around how far to take this async thing.

Comment: How many passengers can a car fit?

Comment: Where I'm from, between 2 and 6, depending on what you call a car.

Comment: So can mysql handle between 10 and 100000 requests per second, depending on server, database size and queries

Answer (score 1):

> How many simultaneous queries can mysql handle?

32 - 64. This is practical limit and you should do a lot of optimisations before you can reach this level. Mysql can handle even more, but performance will start to decrease rather than increase.

> SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE id = ? ORDER BY id

this is bizarre.  WHERE id = ? ORDER BY id? you really mean it?

I think you should join your tables and fetch all the data from mysql at once, and then start to process it. Database can easy become a bottleneck, so you should work with it as optimal as you can.

I am not even sure that you need parallel execution in NodeJS. Try to add data (as mach data as you expecting to have) to your database and try to run your queries and measure performance.

Comment: The node mysql lib is an async library. Have you had any experience using node? It is non blocking so anything that is an expensive resource is async. I was just wondering how far I need to go and if I need to start throttling. 32-64 sounds very low and really surprises me! Got any references to point me to? ps. the query was a typo.

Comment: I have no experience with node. I am talking about database performance. Asynchronous execution allow you to decrease latency for client, but this doesn't matter for database. It still have to process all the queries. /// About 32-64. There are a lot of benchmarks on mysqlperformanceblog.com. They show that throughput of database is limited and usually exhausted at 32 threads. For example http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/07/29/intel-320-ssd-read-performance/

Comment: When you said "I am not even sure that you need parallel execution in NodeJS". I think you should read more about Node. I dont think that 32 threads are the same thing. If they were then my queries wouldn't run atm. Thanks for you suggestions anyway.